# How to change the default delimiter while opening the file

Tags: python, csv, file, delimiter

I would just like to create a csv file and at the same time add my data row by row with a for cicle. Unfortunately I am using textual data so it is not ideal to have a default delimiter like ",". Is it possible to change the delimiter in this phase of the script? how can I do?

```
for x in y:
     newRow = "\n%s,%s\n" % (sentence1, sentence2)
     with open('Mydata.csv', "a") as f:
        f.write(newRow)
```

Comment: Just change the comma in your format string to whatever you want.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `csv` module? It will add quotes around the field if the data contains comma.

Comment: Why would using a comma as a delimiter for a *comma separated value* file be a problem?

Comment: @ScottHunter I think he's saying that the sentences could also contain comma, so it becomes ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Never read or write CSV files by hand (unless you are *really* sure what you're doing). If you miss a single quote or backslash somewhere, you might break the rest of the entire file.

Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the Python standard library (which has several good code samples you can look at):

```py
import csv

with open("Mydata.csv", "a", newline="") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    for x in y:
        newRow = (sentence1, sentence2)
        writer.writerow(newRow)
```

If you want a more full-featured way of loading and saving tabular data, have a look at [Tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/) instead, it's available from PyPI.

Comment: If you're using the `csv` module, you shouldn't need to change the delimiter.

Comment: @ScottHunter that is true. I thought I'd include it anyway as an example, since the original question specifically asked how to change the delimiter. 